# Update with inner join and where conditions

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

I am working on MySQL and created two tables one for `students_data` and one for `Attendance_details`

`Attendance table` has  FK of Student Id 
Here is the `Attendance table`

```
AttID, ID, DateTime, Statues
```

And the `students_data` table

```
fname, lname, ID
ABN   , AA , 123
```

My question:

I want to update the `Attendance_details` table based on student ID like the query below

```
sql = " UPDATE Attendance_table INNER JOIN students_data ON Attendance_table.ID=students_data.ID SET Attendance_table.ID=students_data.ID , Statues=%s , DateTime=%s , WHERE students_data.fname = %s"
val=(1,formatted_date,name)
mycursor.execute(sql,val)
mydb.commit()
```

I got an error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE students_data.fname = 'ABN''
```

Note: I'm working on face recognition project where all faces have a predefined name and compare it with the `students_data`
so the name ABN has been read from face :)

any help or suggestions!

Comment: Please don't SHOUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert data in Attendance table, then avoid UPDATE query. You should use INSERT query and you don't need to JOIN in query.

```
INSERT INTO Attendance_table (ID,Statues,DateTime) SELECT ID, %s as Statues, %s as DateTime FROM students_data WHERE students_data.fname = %s
```

Answer (score 1):

You used an extra comma before where

```
DateTime=%s , WHERE students_data.fname = %s"
```

Remove this comma. Your code should be:

```
sql = " UPDATE Attendance_table INNER JOIN students_data ON Attendance_table.ID=students_data.ID SET Attendance_table.ID=students_data.ID , Statues=%s , DateTime=%s  WHERE students_data.fname = %s"
```

Comment: Why you  use same  ON clause and SET clause 'Attendance_table.ID=students_data.ID'?

Comment: Have your attendance table any exist ID for update?

Comment: No, It will take the ID from Student table

Comment: So you are try to insert new row in attendance table. Right?

Comment: Are you changing your question? Above post describes a syntax error. Data not updating is not mentioned which we need to see data in [reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: @Tushar yes I'm trying to insert

Comment: @Albandry I added another answer for your.  Please check